# Laravel Send Reset Password Using Sentry

Tags: email, laravel

I install laravel with Sentinel(Sentry) but i dont know how to send a password reset using email template from sentinel/Sentry

this is my controller

```
$data = array(
    'hash' => Hash::make($user->id),
    "code" => $user->getResetPasswordCode()
);
$send = Mail::send('sentinel.emails.reset', $data, function($message) use($data) {
    $message->to($data["email"], $data["email"])->subject('Info');
});
```

how to get the code??

Answer (score 0):

Using Sentry

```
$user = Sentry::findUserByLogin($request->input('email'));
$user->getResetPasswordCode()
```